# MapServer WMS on-the-fly reprojection renders only partial image

Tags: coordinate-system, wms, mapserver

When trying to access a WMS that gets on-the-fly reprojected from EPSG:2056 to EPSG:3857, I only receive partially rendered images (see image bolow). The more I zoom in, the worse it gets.

If I access the WMS without reprojection (EPSG:2056) it works fine. The reprojection itself is also fine, the only problem is, that only part of the data gets rendered.

Does someone know why this is happening?

[image: Partially rendered WMS GetMap request]

*Lines should also be rendered in the top part of the image.*

The WMS comes from MapServer. The error-file does not show any errors. Here are some parts of the mapfile:

```
...
PROJECTION
     "init=epsg:2056"
END
...
WEB
     METADATA
          "wms_title" "Title"
          "wms_srs"   "EPSG:2056 EPSG:3857"
          "wms_enable_request" "*"
          "ows_enable_request" "*"
          "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
          "wms_encoding" "ISO-8859-1"
     END
     ...
END   
...
LAYER
     ...
     METADATA
          "wms_enable_request" "*" 
          "wms_server_version" "1.3.0" 
          "wms_srs" "EPSG:2056 EPSG:3857" 
          "wms_include_items" "all" 
          "gml_include_items" "all" 
          "gml_geometries" "geom_gml" 
          "gml_geom_gml_type" "polygone" 
     END
     ...
END
...
```

Comment: What client are you using?  what requests get sent.

Comment: It happens on every client. The request is a normal WMS GetMap request with the following parameters:
SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=layer&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=600&HEIGHT=600&BBOX=...

Comment: I found a workaround for the problem: 
The data that gets displayed comes from a postgis database. Reprojecting the data directly in the query (with ST_Transform()) solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you misunderstand how to tell MapServer what your layer source projection is, and how important that is, and then you have tried to then serve this layer through WMS (without telling MapServer what the source projection is).

Most importantly, first review the "Important Notes" of the Projection object in the MapServer documentation: https://mapserver.org/mapfile/projection.html#important-notes   Specifically:

1. If all of your data in the mapfile is in the same projection, you DO NOT have to specify any projection objects. MapServer will assume that all of the data is in the same projection.
2. Think of the MAP-level projection object as your output projection. The EXTENT and UNITS values at the MAP-level must be in the output projection units. Also, if you have layers in other projections (other than the MAP-level projection) then you must define PROJECTION objects for those layers, to tell MapServer what projections they are in.
3. If you specify a MAP-level projection, and then only one other LAYER projection object, MapServer will assume that all of the other layers are in the specified MAP-level projection.

In your case (assuming that your layer is in EPSG:3857, so you need to tell MapServer that, and then you need to tell MapServer what the output project is) your mapfile could be:

```
MAP

  METADATA
    ...
  END

  PROJECTION
     "init=epsg:2056" #output projection
  END

  LAYER
     ...
     METADATA
       ...
     END
     PROJECTION
       "init=epsg:3857" #source projection
     END
  END #layer
END #map
```

Lastly, verify this mapfile can generate a valid map image, showing your source layer in those output projection extents (before you move to trying through a WMS client) with a `shp2img` command (this utility will be renamed to `map2img` in the upcoming MapServer 8.0 release), such as:

```
  shp2img -m test.map -o ttt.png -all_debug 3
```

Thanks.  and happy mapserv-ing!  -jeff